# Using one dataframe output to find matching rows in another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to use some daily data in one dataframe as a qualifier to run some code in another dataframe. Both dataframes contain ['Date', 'Time', 'Ticker', 'Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close']. One dataframe has only daily information, the other contains 5min out of the same fields, here are some examples.

print(df)

```
       Date     Time Ticker     Open     High      Low    Close
0  01/02/18  3:00 PM     ES  2687.00  2696.00  2681.75  2695.75
1  01/03/18  3:00 PM     ES  2697.25  2714.25  2697.00  2712.50
2  01/04/18  3:00 PM     ES  2719.25  2729.00  2718.25  2724.00
3  01/05/18  3:00 PM     ES  2732.25  2743.00  2726.50  2741.25
4  01/08/18  3:00 PM     ES  2740.25  2748.50  2737.00  2746.50
5  01/09/18  3:00 PM     ES  2751.00  2760.00  2748.00  2753.00
6  01/10/18  3:00 PM     ES  2744.00  2751.75  2736.50  2748.75
7  01/11/18  3:00 PM     ES  2754.25  2768.50  2752.75  2768.00
8  01/12/18  3:00 PM     ES  2771.25  2788.75  2770.00  2786.50
9  01/15/18  3:00 PM     ES  2793.75  2796.00  2792.50  2794.50
```

print(df_tick)

```
           Date      Time Ticker     Open     High      Low    Close
0      01/02/18   8:45 AM     ES  2687.00  2687.25  2681.75  2685.75
1      01/02/18   9:00 AM     ES  2686.00  2687.75  2683.50  2687.50
2      01/02/18   9:15 AM     ES  2687.50  2690.50  2687.25  2689.25
3      01/02/18   9:30 AM     ES  2689.50  2692.00  2689.25  2692.00
4      01/02/18   9:45 AM     ES  2692.00  2692.25  2687.25  2690.00
5      01/02/18  10:00 AM     ES  2690.00  2691.00  2689.75  2690.75
6      01/02/18  10:15 AM     ES  2690.50  2691.25  2690.25  2691.00
7      01/02/18  10:30 AM     ES  2691.00  2692.00  2689.00  2689.50
8      01/02/18  10:45 AM     ES  2689.50  2689.75  2687.75  2688.25
9      01/02/18  11:00 AM     ES  2688.25  2689.50  2687.75  2689.25
10     01/02/18  11:15 AM     ES  2689.25  2690.75  2689.25  2690.00
11     01/02/18  11:30 AM     ES  2690.00  2690.75  2689.25  2690.00
12     01/02/18  11:45 AM     ES  2690.25  2690.50  2688.50  2688.75
13     01/02/18  12:00 PM     ES  2689.00  2689.25  2688.50  2689.25
14     01/02/18  12:15 PM     ES  2689.25  2691.00  2689.00  2690.50
15     01/02/18  12:30 PM     ES  2690.75  2691.00  2689.75  2690.50
16     01/02/18  12:45 PM     ES  2690.75  2691.25  2690.25  2691.00
17     01/02/18   1:00 PM     ES  2691.25  2691.25  2689.50  2690.75
18     01/02/18   1:15 PM     ES  2690.50  2691.50  2690.25  2690.50
19     01/02/18   1:30 PM     ES  2690.50  2691.00  2689.75  2690.75
20     01/02/18   1:45 PM     ES  2690.75  2691.50  2690.25  2690.75
21     01/02/18   2:00 PM     ES  2690.75  2691.25  2690.75  2691.00
22     01/02/18   2:15 PM     ES  2691.25  2691.75  2690.50  2691.50
23     01/02/18   2:30 PM     ES  2691.50  2693.00  2691.50  2692.75
24     01/02/18   2:45 PM     ES  2693.00  2693.75  2691.00  2693.75
25     01/02/18   3:00 PM     ES  2693.75  2696.00  2693.25  2695.75
26     01/03/18   8:45 AM     ES  2697.25  2702.25  2697.00  2700.75
27     01/03/18   9:00 AM     ES  2701.00  2703.75  2700.50  2703.25
28     01/03/18   9:15 AM     ES  2703.25  2706.00  2703.00  2705.00
29     01/03/18   9:30 AM     ES  2705.00  2707.25  2704.00  2706.50
```

Code for calculating the gap percentage

```
#Calculating Gap Percentage
df['Gap %'] = (df['Open'].sub(df['Close'].shift()).div(df['Close'] - 
1).fillna(0))*100
```

I have the code for the df to find the percentage change from Close-Open, and would like to use this information as a qualifier to run some code on the df_tick.

For example if df['Gap %'] > .02, then I want to use that date in df_tick and ignore (or drop) the rest of the information.

```
#drop rows not meeting certain percentage
df.drop(df[df['Gap %'] < .2].index, inplace=True)
```

print(df)

```
       Date     Time Ticker     Open    High      Low    Close   Gap     Gap %
2  01/04/18  3:00 PM     ES  2719.25  2729.0  2718.25  2724.00  6.75  0.247888
3  01/05/18  3:00 PM     ES  2732.25  2743.0  2726.50  2741.25  8.25  0.301067
9  01/15/18  3:00 PM     ES  2793.75  2796.0  2792.50  2794.50  7.25  0.259531
```

Now I'd like to use df['Date'] to find the matching Dates in df_tick['Date'] for some code I've already written, I tried to just drop all the data where the dates aren't the same. But received an error.

```
#drop rows in df_tick not matching dates in df
df_tick.drop(df_tick[df_tick['Date'] != df['Date']].index, inplace=True)

ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be able to reset the index of both dataframes and get away with what you are trying to do, but I would try this:

```py
df_tick = df_tick[df_tick.Date.isin(df.Date.unique())]
```